# Como saber si estoy en la ultima fila de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, linq

Cuando quiero comprobar si me encunentro en la ultima fila me da error

```
if (dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow.Index == dgvClasificacion.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            dgvClasificacion.Rows.Add();

        }
```

Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia del objeto en la linea del if

Comment: Como enlazas dicha lista al `DataGridView`?

Comment: Es una lista que esta enlazada al DGV la cual trae registros, lo que quiero a esos datos que trae el DGV agregarle una nueva fila para poder ingresar un nuevo registro

Comment: No puedes 'setear' la propiedad `AllowUserToAddRows` a true? De esa forma cuando te situes en la ultima columna de la ultima fila, al presionar enter se creará una nueva fila.

Comment: NaCI reformule la pregunta solo quiero comprobar si estoy en la ultima fila de un DGV

Comment: En ese caso, qué evento controlas con  el codigo que posteaste en la pregunta?

Comment: Estoy en el evento click de un boton

Comment: He recreado tu caso de alguna forma y creo que tu problema no está dentro de ese if, y ese error es un problema de instancias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por el mensaje del problema que mencionas lo mas seguro es que el CurrentRow este en `null` porque no hay minguna row seleccionada

```
if(dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow == null)
    return;

var lastRow = dgvClasificacion.Rows[dgvClasificacion.Rows.Count - 1];

if (dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow == lastRow)
{
    dgvClasificacion.Rows.Add();
}
```